# How can I get Django Channels to handle a higher message frequency?

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I'm trying to build a multiplayer, fast-paced, side-scrolling platformer game called Star Jumper using vanilla-js on canvas and Django-Channels for websockets.  I'm having trouble getting enough messages through the server to make the lag playable.  Messages sent to the server include key-down/up, mouse clicks and periodic reconciliations. To troubleshoot I focused on just the periodic reconciliation, setting up 2 counters on the redis-server within consumers.py - (1) reconciliation received from client and (2) reconciliation sent to the opposing client.  With 2 players in the game, the server's messages received counter starts to outpace the messages sent counter at around 10 per second (2 players, 20 total per second).  I'm hoping that I'm just doing something wrong, that Django Channels can handle more than 20 total messages per second, but I'm stumped.

Relevant code is below, [repo is here](https://github.com/Chimmahh/StarJumper), happy to clarify/post more.  Within the repo, the "multiplayer.html" template has my animation loop and socket traffic management.

within "StarJumper/templates/multiplayer.html"

```
let socket = new ReconnectingWebSocket(ws_path)
function Reconcile() {
    socket.send(JSON.stringify({
        "command": "reconcile",
        "game": {{ game.id }},
        "client_now": global_now,
        "current": {
            "x_pos": world.player.x_pos,
            "y_pos": world.player.y_pos,
            "vy": world.player.vy,
            "color": world.player.color,
        }
    }))
}
```

within "StarJumper/app/consumers.py"...

```
async def receive_json(self, content):
    game = await get_game_or_error(content["game"], self.scope["user"])
    command = content.get("command", None)
    if command == "join":
        await self.join_game(content)
    elif command == "reconcile":
        msg_ct = cache.get("msg_ct")
        cache.set("msg_ct", msg_ct + 1, timeout=CACHE_TTL)
        await self.reconcile_group(content)
    # other commands stripped out for this post

async def join_game(self, content):
    # other join stuff stripped out for post
    cache.set("msg_ct", 0, timeout=CACHE_TTL)
    cache.set("thru_ct", 0, timeout=CACHE_TTL)
    cache.set(game.group_name + "." + self.scope["user"].username + ".client_now", 0, timeout=CACHE_TTL)

async def reconcile_group(self, content):
    game = await get_game_or_error(content["game"], self.scope["user"])
    if cache.get(game.group_name + "." + self.scope["user"].username + ".client_now") < content["client_now"]:
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            game.group_name,
            {
                "type": "reconcile.client",
                "username": self.scope["user"].username,
                "current": content["current"],
                "game": game.group_name,
            }
        )
        cache.set(game.group_name + "." + self.scope["user"].username + ".client_now", content["client_now"], timeout=CACHE_TTL)

async def reconcile_client(self, event):
    if event["username"] != self.scope["user"].username:
        thru_ct = cache.get("thru_ct")
        cache.set("thru_ct", thru_ct + 1, timeout=CACHE_TTL)
        msg_ct = cache.get("msg_ct")
        print(msg_ct, thru_ct, msg_ct - thru_ct)
        await self.send_json(
            {
                "type": "reconcile",
                "username": event["username"],
                "current": event["current"],
            }
        )
```